# Bimeromorphic equivalence of reduced spaces for Kähler $S^1$-actions

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, dg.differential-geometry, complex-geometry, kahler-manifolds

Let $(X,\omega)$ be a smooth Kähler manifold (not necessarily compact) with an isometric $S^1$-action with a Hamiltonian $H$. It is a *well known fact* that

1) The reduced spaces $X(c)=H^{-1}(c)/S^1$ have a complex analytic structure.

2) Such spaces are bimeromorphic for $c$ satisfying $\min(H)<c<\max(H)$.

I was not able to find a reference for these facts and would be very grateful if you can give me one.

**PS.** In fact I'll be happy with a user-friendly reference for the case when $X$ is a smooth projective  complex manifold.

Comment: For the first part of your question : It is due to holomorphic slice theorem, see p.18 and Theorem 2.6 of https://arxiv.org/pdf/alg-geom/9304004.pdf . This gives a right answer to the first part of your question. It seems that Sjamaar first solved this question in 1993 . About part 2 .in your case , symplectic quotiens are birational together due to  V. Guillemin and S. Sternberg, Birational equivalence in the symplectic category, Invent. Math. 97 (1989),
485–522

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have not read it, but I think the article Heinzner-Loose, "Reduction of complex Hamiltonian G-spaces" (1994, [link](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1274117)) may be the original reference for your first question.

In the compact (but not necessarily projective) case, both questions are treated in Fujiki, "Kähler quotient and equivariant cohomology" (1994, [link](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1397979)).

I would also be interested in seeing a reference for the second fact in the non-compact case -- let me know if you find one!

Comment: Dear Macbeth, many thanks for these references!